# Cosine similarity Vectors that need to have same size

Tags: neo4j, similarity, trigonometry

I want to calculate similarity between an open role that need X,Y,Z skills with W,T,L level of expertise (proficiency) and differente employees... BUT not all the employees are going to have all X,Y,Z skills so we will need to put a 0 if skill is not present.... 
What I have is not working since is just matching when both the role and the employee has the skill. Any idea? Thanks in advance

```
MATCH (p1:Employee)-[x:HAS_SKILL]->(sk:Personal_Skill)<-[y:REQUIRES_SKILL] -(p2:Role {name:'Role 1-Analytics Manager'})
WITH SUM(x.proficiency * y.proficiency) AS xyDotProduct,
SQRT(REDUCE(xDot = 0.0, a IN COLLECT(x.proficiency) | xDot + a^2)) AS xLength,
SQRT(REDUCE(yDot = 0.0, b IN COLLECT(y.proficiency) | yDot + b^2)) AS yLength,
p1, p2
MERGE (p1)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(p2)
SET s.similarity = xyDotProduct / (xLength * yLength)
RETURN  p1.name, s.similarity
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to this one is breaking up your MATCHes into several, usage of an OPTIONAL MATCH, and using COALESCE() to get a default value for a null.

First step is to MATCH on all the skills required of the role.

Next is to MATCH on all employees.

Last is an OPTIONAL MATCH from the employee to the skill, which will give us a null for the HAS_SKILL relationship if the employee doesn't have the skill.

From there, we get the proficiencies, using COALESCE() to give a default of 0 where HAS_SKILL is null.

```
MATCH (sk:Personal_Skill)<-[y:REQUIRES_SKILL] -(p2:Role {name:'Role 1-Analytics Manager'})
MATCH (p1:Employee)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p1)-[x:HAS_SKILL]->(sk)
WITH p1, COALESCE(x.proficiency, 0) as xProf, y.proficiency as yProf, p2
WITH SUM(xProf * yProf) AS xyDotProduct,
SQRT(REDUCE(xDot = 0.0, a IN COLLECT(xProf) | xDot + a^2)) AS xLength,
SQRT(REDUCE(yDot = 0.0, b IN COLLECT(yProf) | yDot + b^2)) AS yLength,
p1, p2
MERGE (p1)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(p2)
SET s.similarity = xyDotProduct / (xLength * yLength)
RETURN  p1.name, s.similarity
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to solve it with this and also used the COALESCE for other thing I was trying to do.